# Como crio um Team Project, fazendo branch do código de outro Team Project no TFS 2013?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Até a versão 2012 do TFS era possível criar um novo Team Project, iniciando o repositório de código fazendo branch de outro Team Project, figura abaixo, porém essa opção não está mais disponível no TFS 2013. Existe alguma maneira?

[image: New Team Project wizard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://bit.ly/TFSPowerTools13), além da opção de não criar uma pasta para código fonte atrelada ao Team Project, opção que nunca esteve disponível no wizard, te dá a opção de criar uma Branch. Veja abaixo como vizualizar informações sobre o comando:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools>tfpt createteamproject /?
```

Dentre as diversas opções temos /sourcecontrol, e esse parâmetro pode criar uma nova pasta e dar um nome, ou não criar uma pasta, para um projeto que não seja de software; ou Branchpath…

```
/sourcecontrol Specifies source control options: 'New' to create a new source control
tree; 'None' to create a project without source control support; 
'Branch:branchpath' to branch from an existing path on the TFS server. 
For the Branch option: if the branchpath does not exist on the TFS server, 
a list of existing paths are printed.
```

Lembrando que o path é o caminho no TFVC.

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente você tem que primeiro criar o time pra depois iniciar o branch:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ad0c44f-c269-44ea-bc1b-59bb597d7fc9/create-a-new-source-control-branch-in-tfs-2013?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: Não posso criar um Time para um Team Project que ainda não existe!